# How to create Java array in Kotlin for @PropertySource?

Tags: java, arrays, spring, kotlin

I am trying to configure @PropertySource for my Spring-based application.

In Java, I could do something like this:

```
@PropertySource(value = {"application.properties","other.properties" })
```

I tried `arrayOf` in Kotlin but I end up with a type mismatch:

```
@PropertySource(value = arrayOf("application.properties", "other.properties"))
```

What is the right way to go here?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `value` annotation parameter is handled in a special way in Kotlin (following its special handling in Java), and if it has an array type, Kotlin converts it to a `vararg`. Therefore, the correct syntax here is simply:

```
@PropertySource("application.properties", "other.properties")
```

If you do want to specify the parameter name explicitly, use the spread operator to expand the array into varargs:

```
@PropertySource(value = *arrayOf("application.properties", "other.properties"))
```

For any other array annotation parameter, you should simply use `arrayOf()` normally.

Answer (score 3):

Adding this in case it helps anyone...

I needed multiple instances of the same annotation, but I also needed to set other attributes of the annotation.

```
@Configuration
@PropertySources(
        PropertySource(
                value = ["classpath:consul.properties"]),
        PropertySource(
                value = ["file:/run/example/consul.properties"],
                ignoreResourceNotFound = true)
)
```